# Model of writing a block of data to memory

Tags: alloy

I created an Alloy model of writing a block of data to a memory of fixed size. See below. The instances that the Alloy Analyzer generates all contain blocks of size one (i.e., blocks that have one data) or less. I would like the Alloy Analyzer to generate instances with blocks of size two. So, I added this to the `writeBlock` predicate: `#block = 2`. This is the updated predicate:

```
pred writeBlock (m, m': Memory, block: set Data) {
    some addrs: set m.data.Data {
        #addrs = #block
        #block = 2   // I added this
        m'.data = m.data ++ (addrs -> block)
    }
}
```

But then the Analyzer says "No instances found."

Why?

Why are there no instances?

```
module fixedSizeMemory [Addr, Data]

sig Memory {
    data: Addr -> one Data
}

// Write a block of data to memory.
pred writeBlock (m, m': Memory, block: set Data) {
    some addrs: set m.data.Data {
        #addrs = #block
        m'.data = m.data ++ (addrs -> block)
    }
}

pred Show {}
run writeBlock
```

Update: I figured out why there are no instances when `#block = 2` is added. The problem is with `(addrs -> block)`. That says: take all permutations of `addrs` values and `block` values. So, if there are 2 `addrs` value and 2 `block` values, then there will be 4 permutations. The `data` relation says that each `Addr` value maps to one `Data` value. But the 4 permutations will violate that constraint. The only `blocks` that don't violate the relation are those `blocks` of size 1 or 0.

**Update#2**: I solved the problem. Here is Alloy code to write a block of memory:

```
// Write a block of data to memory. That is,
// overwrite the data at a set of addresses
// with values in block.
pred writeBlock (m, m': Memory, block: set Data) {
       // Non-deterministically select a subset 
       // of m's addresses to be overwritten.
       some addresses: set m.data.Data {
           // The chunk of memory overwritten
           // matches the size of the block.
           #addresses = #block
           // Create a temporary relation, mapping.
           // It defines a mapping from each address
           // selected above to a block value. The
           // relation is 1:1. That is, each address is
           // assigned a value from block, and each
           // value in block is associated to an address.
           some mapping: addresses one -> one block {
               // Overwrite the selected portion of memory
               // with mapping.
               m'.data = m.data ++ mapping
              // This is so cool!
         }
    }
}
```